# Is it possible to use NSMutableAttributedString with SKLabelNode?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, sprite-kit, kerning

I'm trying to change the kerning on a couple of SKLabelNodes. I tried to use some code from another answer:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString;
attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Please get wider"];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName value:@5 range:NSMakeRange(10, 5)];
[self.label setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

This isn't allowed:

```
[myLabelNode setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

And this doesn't carry over the changes I made:

```
myLabelNode.text = attributedString.string;
```

Is it possible to change kerning on an SKLabelNode?

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 11, NSAttributedStrings are supported in SKLabelNode. So kerning and other options should now be available to you.